# How can I make parts of the source code "folded" (hidden) in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift

In the Visual Basic.Net I can use

```
#Region "identifier_string" #End Region
```

to "fold" (hide) parts of the source code in the editor.

How can I do that in Swift ?

Comment: What is a "folding zone"?

Comment: Something like this 
[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd032a17.aspx)

Comment: Not really possible in Swift, but you can use `// MARK: Your Title` to structure your code and be able to jump to those marks in the file inspector

Comment: @OsamaJassim Thanks, I've edited your question with the additional info so that everyone can understand what you're referring to.

Comment: This would be such a welcomed ability.  My mind requires folded code to get a bigger picture of things, and my object-scoped variables always intrude on the folded view.  To be able to enclose them into a region of collapsibility would be awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Eric D.'s answer is perfect.

If you want to mark down some regions then you can use it like as :

**// MARK:**

Will be preceded by a horizontal divider

**// MARK: your text goes here**

Puts 'your text goes here' in bold in the drop down list

**// MARK: - your text goes here**

Puts 'your text goes here' in bold in the drop down list, preceded by a horizontal divider

Comment: Who is @Eric D.? However, I don't think this answers the question. **// MARK:** is not intended to fold code. 
Xcode gives you the folding ribbons, but is based in scope. As far as I know you can't fold based on _regions_, I mean, what if you just want to fold a couple of funcions. You have to go manually folding each of them. Am I right

Comment: @Ozx This is old question.

Comment: but still relevant. As Xcode 10, to the best of my knowledge it hasn't been implemented a feature like that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can "fold" parts of the code in Xcode, by clicking on the left side in the gutter at the beginning of a function, class or other block of code.

Before:

[image: unfolded]

After:

[image: folded]

*Red arrow: where you click, Orange arrow: the resulting folded function.*

Comment: "Code folding ribbon" option in Xcode->Preferences->Text Editing needs to be selected. Otherwise no such option visible

Comment: Thanks @Alfishe, this really helped, since i come from a .Net background and folding is essential for me for readability. Much appreciated.